# Meaning of $A^{25}$ in toroidal compactification of open strings

Tags: string-theory, compactification

In ch-$8$ sec-$8.6$ (String theory vol $1$) Polchinski starts with “a constant background” U$(1)$ gauge field when doing toroidal compactification of an open string and mention this gauge field
$$A_{25}(x^M)=-\frac{\theta}{2\pi R}\tag{8.6.1}$$

While discussing Chan-Paton factors $U(n)$; $A_{25}$ formulae is modified to
$$A_{25}=-\frac{1}{2\pi R}diag(\theta_1,\theta_2…\theta_n)$$

I’m not getting what is this $A_{25}$ field? When we do toroidal compactification on $1$ dimension of a spacetime with $d+1$ dimension we get a scalar $g_{dd}$ and a gauge field $A_{\mu}=g_{d\mu}$ where $\mu=0,1,2,3…d-1$, so this $A_{25}$ is different from this gauge field. Moreover in case of CP factor this $A_{25}$ is becoming a matrix of dimension $n\times n$. I’m unable to see relationship between compactification and this gauge field.

Comment: One massless mode of a non-compact closed string is the metric. You can compactify it to get an abelian gauge field. One massless mode of a non-compact open string is a non-abelian gauge field. You can compactify it to get a Lie algebra valued scalar which is what $A_{25}$ is.